# How to optimize my code to solve Hackerrank problem "Climbing the leaderboard"?

Tags: python

The link for the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem

For my solution, it passes both the "run code" test cases, but on submit, it only passes 8 of the 12 test cases, but fails 4 due to timeout. I am guessing the solution itself is correct. Any ideas please on how to optimize the solution?

Some small test cases:

```
# Small Test case 1
ranked = [100, 90, 90, 80] ## already in descending order
player = [70, 80, 105]
## expected ans = [4, 3, 1]

# Small Test case 2
ranked = [100, 90, 90, 80] ## already in descending order
player = [70, 90, 105]
## expected ans = [4, 2, 1]

# Small Test case 3
ranked = [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10] ## already in descending order
player = [5, 25, 50, 120]
## expected ans = [6, 4, 2, 1]
```

My solution:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(_r, _p):
    #print(f"Params passed:\nranked={_r}\nplayer={_p}")
    ans = list()
    for pidx, pscore in enumerate(_p):
        #print(f"\nPos {pidx} : Player score = {pscore}")
        crank = 1 ## set current rank as 1 at start of evaluation of a player score
        if pscore >= _r[0]:
            ans.append(1)
            continue
        for ridx, rscore in enumerate(_r[1:]):
            #print(f"ridx={ridx} , RankedScore={rscore} , PlayerScore = {pscore} , crank={crank}")
            if rscore < _r[ridx]: ## current ranked score < previous ranked score
                crank += 1
            if pscore >= rscore:
                ans.append(crank)
                break
        else:
            ans.append(crank+1)
        #print(f"now ans={ans}")
    return ans

print(f"\n\nFinal answer = {f1(ranked, player)}")
```

Comment: Assuming they're giving you a large list, creating `_r[1:]` in each loop will take time.  You can save that time by creating that sublist once and reusing it, but really you don't even need that.  You can run the loop from `(1,len(_r))` and use `ridx-1`

Comment: Hi. Not totally sure how you meant I should implement your ideas without having to use two loops. The code below is best I could come up with as of now, but the same 4 test cases still fail. The problem states the "ranked" and "player" list could contain up to 10e5 entries.

Comment: Code:
def climbingLeaderboard(_r, _p):
    ans = list()
    _r1 = sorted(set(_r), reverse=True)
    len_r1 = len(_r1)
    ranked_sublist = _r1[1:]
    for pscore in _p:
        crank = 1 ## set current rank as 1 at start of evaluation of a player score
        if pscore >= _r1[0]:
            ..same logic...
        for i in range(1, len_r1):
            ...same logic as before but using _r1[i] < _r1[i-1]
    return ans

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious time loss is that you're using a linear search, which is **O(n)** for `n` existing players.  The next is that you throw away *all* of your learning in between searches, so you have to do `m` independent searches for the `m` scores you place.

Replace the linear search with a binary search on `_r` (of length `n`).  This will speed you up enough to likely pass the timing tests.  However, for better efficiency, remember where the last score was found, so you don't search areas of `_r` that you *know* cannot contain the next score.  For instance, if you find the first score would fit at `_r[idx1]`, then your next binary search should cover only `_r[:indx1]` (the player scores are in ascending order, so you don't have to search any lower positions on the ranking board).

Can you take it from there?

---

For additional speed, you can make some assumptions about the distribution of scores on the leaderboard.  In the real world, this is reasonable, especially with a very large leaderboard.  If you use a straightforward interpolation search, you will save even more time in the expected case.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Let me try it out and see how far I get. Thank you!